# how to develop word search, HTML5

Tags: html, search, cpu-word

I need to develop a search of words such as link,

http://www.educaplay.com/es/recursoseducativos/846841/sopa_de_letras.htm

and let me know I need to learn in order to develop it. HTML5 Besides, what else would need to learn?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you might start with some basic languages like: HTML, CSS (to style the output), JavaScript(To write them dynamically) The server side should be ASP.NET Here is the link: [ASP.NET Official Website](http://asp.net).
And the link about search for words is here: [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163355.aspx)

Comment: I have basic knowledge of html, css and javascript, I q help, I found this jquery plugin

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-wordsearch-game/

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to do it is using a jQuery widget.

You need to know HTML, CSS and JAVASCRIPT. (no need server side technologies)

This is **an example** of jQuery widget:

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-wordsearch-game/

Javascipt Usage:

```
$("#aDiv").wordsearchwidget({"wordlist" : words,"gridsize" : 12});

    parameters:
    gridsize - Size of grid to generate (this will be a square)
    wordlist - Comma separated list of words to place on the grid
```

This is **another example** in Javascript:
http://jswordsearch.sourceforge.net/

You can download and modify the script(javascript) of Normal and Lite version.

Comment: I edited the answer adding new info, but the link is the most important to go widget's page and download it.